# Using <s:combobox> in Struts 1

Tags: combobox, struts, taglib

I am using Struts 1.I have a taglibrary

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tags.tld" %>
```

This tag library works only in Struts 2.0 Framework.This has a tag  which I have used in my application.Now when I had to backtrack to Struts 1 I got an error

> Could not parse deployment descriptor:
>   java.io.IOException: cannot resolve
>   '/WEB-INF/struts-tags.tld' into a
>   valid tag library probably occurred
>   due to an error

Can anyone suggest how to use  in struts 1

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
```

Then use html:select with the appropiate attributes as explained in the [official documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.8/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#html:select).

```
<html:select property="...">
...
</html:select>
```